# Big differences between MS Translator API results and Bing Translator Results. Why?

Tags: microsoft-translator, bing-translator-api

Bing Translator claims to use MS Translator. However, there can be serious differences between the translations provided by MS Transalator and the translations provided by Bing. Most of the time, Bing translations look much better.

Can someone tell me if there are some specific parameter values or options that should be set in MS-Translator such that the translations are equal (or closer) to those of Bing? 
Is there any special subscription (paid if required) to get better quality translations in MS-Translator?  (I mean: closer to the Bing ones)

We currently have a paid subscription to MS-Translator and we are using the "Translate" function of the MSTranslator API.
`... https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/Translate?appid=Bearer%20"${bearer}"\&from="${lang_from}"\&to=en\&contentType=text%2Fplain\&category=general`

A couple of examples with Simplified Chinese:
Original Taiwanese wording:
"不專業，經追問不願多講。"

English translation that we received from MS Translator:
"Not professional, asking reluctant to speak."

Bing translation: 
"Unprofessional, after questioning unwilling to speak more."

Example II:

Original Taiwanese wording:
"廠地設備老舊，而且進廠車輛多顯得很混亂很壅擠。"

English translation that we received from MS Translator:
"Old factory to equipment and incoming vehicles appear very confusion was obstructing squeeze."

Bing translation: 
"Factory equipment is old, and the number of vehicles in the factory seems very confusing and congested."

Answer (score 1):

Using the parameter &category=generalnn in the API call will produce the same results as you see in the Bing UI.
Be careful with tagged content. Tags are handled better with the default category value, blank or "general".

Comment: thank you so much. do you have any source for other categories?